# QtConcurrent::map shows no benefit

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt, qtconcurrent

I want to manipulate a `QVector` using the `QtConcurrent::map` function. All my sample program does is to increment all values in a `QVector` by 1.

```
QVector<double> arr(10000000, 0);
QElapsedTimer timer;
qDebug() << QThreadPool::globalInstance()->maxThreadCount() << "Threads";

int end;
/* * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * */
timer.start();
for(int i = 0; i < 100; ++i) {
    std::transform(arr.begin(), arr.end(), arr.begin(), [](double x){ return ++x; });
}
end = timer.elapsed();
qDebug() << end;
/* * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * */
timer.start();
for(int i = 0; i < 100; ++i) {
    std::for_each(arr.begin(), arr.end(), [](double &x){ ++x; });
}
end = timer.elapsed();
qDebug() << end;
/* * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * */
timer.start();
for(int i = 0; i < 100; ++i) {
    QFuture<void> qf = QtConcurrent::map(arr.begin(), arr.end(), [](double &x){ ++x; });
    qf.waitForFinished();
}
end = timer.elapsed();
qDebug() << end;
```

However the program outputs

```
4 Threads
905 // std::transform
886 // std::for_each
876 // QtConcurrent::map
```

so there is almost no speed benefit with the multithreaded version. I verified that there are actually 4 threads running. I used -O2 optimization. Is the more common `QThreadPool` approach better suited for this situation?

**EDIT:**

I tried a differernt method using `QtConcurrent::run()`. Here are the relevant parts of the program code:

```
void add1(QVector<double>::iterator first, QVector<double>::iterator last) {
    for(; first != last; ++first) {
        *first += 1;
    }
}

/* * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * */
std::for_each(arr.begin(), arr.end(), [](double &x){ ++x; });
/* * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * */
QFuture<void> qf[numThreads];
for(int j = 0; j < numThreads; ++j) {
    qf[j] = QtConcurrent::run(add1, arr.begin()+j*n/numThreads, arr.begin()+(j+1)*n/numThreads-1);
}
for(int j = 0; j < numThreads; ++j) {
    qf[j].waitForFinished();
}
```

So I manually distribute the task over different threads. But still I hardly get a performance boost:

```
181 ms // std::for_each
163 ms // QtConcurrent::run
```

What's still wrong here?

Comment: Why would you expect a speed-up? You're waiting for the future in each loop iteration.

Comment: I'm not an expert in this field but I expect map() to start 4 Threads which should make this code line finish faster than the STL functions. Or did I misunderstand the concept of this function?

Answer (score 4):

It appears QtConcurrent has a high overhead compared to simply using C++ threading primitives and roll-your-own-thread-pools.

```
template<class T>
struct threaded_queue {
  using lock = std::unique_lock<std::mutex>;
  void push_back( T t ) {
    {
      lock l(m);
      data.push_back(std::move(t));
    }
    cv.notify_one();
  }
  boost::optional<T> pop_front() {
    lock l(m);
    cv.wait(l, [this]{ return abort || !data.empty(); } );
    if (abort) return {};
    auto r = std::move(data.back());
    data.pop_back();
    return std::move(r);
  }
  void terminate() {
    {
      lock l(m);
      abort = true;
      data.clear();
    }
    cv.notify_all();
  }
  ~threaded_queue()
  {
    terminate();
  }
private:
  std::mutex m;
  std::deque<T> data;
  std::condition_variable cv;
  bool abort = false;
};
struct thread_pool {
  thread_pool( std::size_t n = 1 ) { start_thread(n); }
  thread_pool( thread_pool&& ) = delete;
  thread_pool& operator=( thread_pool&& ) = delete;
  ~thread_pool() = default; // or `{ terminate(); }` if you want to abandon some tasks
  template<class F, class R=std::result_of_t<F&()>>
  std::future<R> queue_task( F task ) {
    std::packaged_task<R()> p(std::move(task));
    auto r = p.get_future();
    tasks.push_back( std::move(p) );
    return r;
  }
  template<class F, class R=std::result_of_t<F&()>>
  std::future<R> run_task( F task ) {
    if (threads_active() >= total_threads()) {
      start_thread();
    }
    return queue_task( std::move(task) );
  }
  void terminate() {
    tasks.terminate();
  }
  std::size_t threads_active() const {
    return active;
  }
  std::size_t total_threads() const {
    return threads.size();
  }
  void clear_threads() {
    terminate();
    threads.clear();
  }
  void start_thread( std::size_t n = 1 ) {
    while(n-->0) {
      threads.push_back(
        std::async( std::launch::async,
          [this]{
            while(auto task = tasks.pop_front()) {
              ++active;
              try{
                (*task)();
              } catch(...) {
                --active;
                throw;
              }
              --active;
            }
          }
        )
      );
    }
  }
private:
  std::vector<std::future<void>> threads;
  threaded_queue<std::packaged_task<void()>> tasks;
  std::atomic<std::size_t> active = {};
};

struct my_timer_t {
    std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::time_point first;
    std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::duration duration;

    void start() {
        first = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    }
    std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::duration finish() {
        return duration = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now()-first;
    }
    unsigned long long ms() const {
        return std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(duration).count();
    }
};
int main() {
    std::vector<double> arr(1000000, 0);
    my_timer_t timer;

    /* * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * */
    timer.start();
    for(int i = 0; i < 100; ++i) {
        std::transform(arr.begin(), arr.end(), arr.begin(), [](double x){ return ++x; });
    }
    timer.finish();
    auto time_transform = timer.ms();
    std::cout << time_transform << "<- std::transform (" << arr[rand()%arr.size()] << ")\n";
    /* * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * */
    timer.start();
    for(int i = 0; i < 100; ++i) {
        std::for_each(arr.begin(), arr.end(), [](double &x){ ++x; });
    }
    timer.finish();
    auto time_for_each = timer.ms();
    std::cout << time_for_each << "<- std::for_each (" << arr[rand()%arr.size()] << ")\n";
    /* * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * */
    enum { num_threads = 8 };
    thread_pool pool(num_threads);
    timer.start();
    for(int i = 0; i < 100; ++i) {
        std::array< std::future<void>, num_threads > tasks;
        for (int t = 0; t < num_threads; ++t) {
            tasks[t] = pool.run_task([&,t]{
                std::for_each( arr.begin()+(arr.size()/num_threads)*t, arr.begin()+(arr.size()/num_threads)*(t+1), [](double& x){++x;} );
            });
        }
        // std::cout << "loop! -- " << pool.threads_active() << "/" << pool.total_threads() << std::endl;
        for (int t = 0; t < num_threads; ++t)
            tasks[t].wait();
    }
    timer.finish();
    auto time_pool = timer.ms();
    std::cout << time_pool << "<- thread_pool (" << arr[rand()%arr.size()] << ")\n";
}
```

[Live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/977833aca01dd03b).

This generates:

```
153<- std::transform (100)
131<- std::for_each (200)
82<- thread_pool (300)
```

a significant speedup when using a simple C++11 thread pool to split tasks 8 ways.  (It was about 105 when splitting tasks 4 ways).

Now I did use a test set 10 times smaller than yours, as the online system timed out when my program took that long to run.

There is going to be overhead communicating with your thread pool system, but my naive thread pool shouldn't be outperforming a real library like this.

Now, a serious problem is that you might be memory IO-bound; more threads accessing bytes faster won't help if you all have to wait for the bytes.

Comment: How did you tested the overhead of `QtConcurrent`? Note that you grouped the `++` operation into `num_threads` batches. You could do this with `QtConcurrent` too.

Comment: @m7913d That is what `QtConcurrent` is supposed to do; launch a number of sub-threads to handle part of the task based on the number of hardware threads.  I just did it manually.  I was getting significant speedups over `for_each`.

Comment: `QtConcurrent` distributes each operation to a thread (taking a maximum number of concurrent threads into account). It does not group them. Note that it is not straight forward to group operations correctly if they may not take the same amount of time.

Comment: @m7913d Oh, that does suck.

Comment: I was wrong, Qt implements some grouping by looking at the user and overhead time. It starts with one operation per batch and doubles it every time the overhead is large compared to the user execution time. Therefore, a lot of trials are needed before using large batches and hence a lot of overhead.

Comment: I'm unable to reproduce your result, probably due to IO-bound as you suggested. @NullAchtFuffZehn Does it work for you?